# How to send mail with attachment in lambda nodeJs using SES service

Tags: email, aws-lambda, attachment, amazon-ses

I am trying to send a mail with attachment.
I have already used SES service for sending simple and HTML content mail. but now I want to send a mail with attachments.

I am using amazon SES service for sending emails and I am using the 'sendRawEmail' method for send mail with attachments.

I am getting an error message like this.`InvalidParameterValue: Nested group`

I didn't find any Node examples for this type of error.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a very frustrating time trying to send emails with NodeJS SES API.
I found the issue and i fixed that with using `mailcomposer` npm package.
Now I an able to send a Mails with attachments.

Install AWS SDK

```
npm i aws-sdk
```

Now Install manilcomposer

```
npm i mailcomposer
```

Full code below

Request body: 
if you want to send mail With Base64 content.

```
{
  email: ['jen****@gmail.com', 'Aa****@gmail.com'],
  from: 'no-reply@*****.com',
  subject: 'Sending emails with attachments',
  text: 'please find attachments',
  attachments: [{
    filename: 'sample.pdf',
    content: {{file}}, // file content base64 staring
    encoding: 'base64',
  }]
}
```

if you want to send a mail with the file path.

```
{
      email: ['jen****@gmail.com', 'Aa****@gmail.com'],
      from: 'no-reply@*****.com',
      subject: 'Sending emails with attachments',
      text: 'please find attachments',
      attachments: [{
        filename: 'sample.pdf',
        path: './home/sample,pdf'
      }]
    }
```

Business logic Code:

```
const ses = new AWS.SES({ region: 'us-east-1' }); //specify region for the particular see service.

const mailcomposer = require('mailcomposer');

exports.handler = function (event, context) {
  console.log('Event: ',JSON.stringify(event));

  if (!event.email) {
    context.fail('Missing argument: email');
    return;
  }

  if (!event.subject) {
    context.fail('Missing argument: subject');
  }

  if (!event.from) {
    context.fail('Missing argument: from');
  }

  if (!event.html && !event.text) {
    context.fail('Missing argument: html|text');
  }

  const to = event.email;
  const from = event.from;
  const subject = event.subject;
  const htmlBody = event.html; 
  const textBody = event.text;
  const attachments = event.attachments;

  const mailOptions = {
    from: from,
    subject: subject,
    text: textBody,
    html: htmlBody,
    to: to,
    attachments: attachments ? attachments : []
  };

  const mail = mailcomposer(mailOptions);

  mail.build(function (err, message) {
    const req = ses.sendRawEmail({ RawMessage: { Data: message } });

    req.on('build', function () {
      req.httpRequest.headers['Force-headers'] = '1';
    });

    req.send(function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack);
        context.fail('Internal Error: The email could not be sent.');
      } else {
        console.log(message);
        console.log('The email was successfully sent')
        context.succeed('The email was successfully sent');
      }
    });
  });
};

if you have and any query regarding mailcomposer then check [here][1] this link below

  [1]: https://nodemailer.com/extras/mailcomposer/
```